# How do I judge a conference's trustworthiness?

Tags: conference, funding

I asked a question here [How are travel expenses paid by conferences?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/106767/how-are-travel-expenses-paid-by-conferences) , and the answer mentioned that it depends on how well I trust a conference (to pay back expenses).

That raises a new issue - how do I judge a conference's reputation (not in its field but in financial matters). Is there some objective way to judge that?

Comment: If it has been going on for a long time with a good reputation in the field it should be just fine.

Comment: @JonCuster Isn't that just an argument for their relevance in their field? Does it mean they are also fiscally responsible?

Comment: To stick around, the conference has to be fiscally responsible or venues stop booking them. And, if they stiff (do not reimburse) invited speakers that will get known in the community really really quickly and nobody will accept invitations to speak there anymore.

Comment: Careful: I remember, a few years ago, a reputable conference had its abbreviated name hijacked (and temporarily out-googled) by a scam conference and only careful reading of the PC and keynote speaker list would reveal that.

Answer (score 2):

Financial reliability is going to be related to scientific validity. Definitely agree with [JonCuster's comment](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/106771/how-do-i-judge-a-conferences-trustworthiness#comment278974_106771) that long-standing conferences (e.g., annually recurring events with a history of substantive organizers and programs) are more trustworthy. Some new conferences are hard to evaluate; this will depend more on who exactly is organizing and whether your network trusts them. Otherwise, this general list could help.

https://libguides.ucd.ie/publishing/predatory

> 1. The conference has an overly ambitious title
> 2. The technical programme is broad. Very broad.
> 3. The language on the conference website is…off
> 4. Renowned organisations are sponsoring a low-profile conference
> 5. The organisers’ contact details are missing, or aren’t quite right
> 6. Another conference with a suspiciously similar name already exists
> 7. The conference or its organisers have known associates
> 8. The organisers are charging higher-than-normal fees
> 9. The conference is unusually frequent

Caltech Library’s list of predatory conferences:

> https://libguides.caltech.edu/c.php?g=512665&p=3503029